# Why do clothing tags say LGG for large?

Tags: etymology

Tags on *large* size T-shirts will often have the letters *LGG* to specify large. Why don't they simply say *LG*?

Is *LGG* simply short for *large/grande*?

Comment: They sure are pedantic about closing questions around here. Well, at least you got an answer.

Comment: @Matt Montag, Yes they are!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LGG is short for Large - Grande - Grande (English, French, Spanish)

similarly for MMM: Medium - Moyenne - Medio